# Why is getch() in C++ waiting for pressing Enter in CLion?

Tags: c++, clion, getch

In CLion getch() is waiting for pressing of Enter button in this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char c = getch();
cout << c;
}
```

How can I fix it?

[image: Terminal]

Comment: What is CLion using for a terminal? If it's a built in terminal, it might not follow the same rules as what `getch` expects from an old DOS terminal emulator. For example, it might buffer and not pass on the input until it sees a new line.

Comment: @ AyxanHaqverdili Win10

Comment: `getch()` waits for the user to type something. Why would you expect it NOT to wait for an `Enter`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau `_getch` from `conio.h` doesn't wait for Enter. CLion seems have its own terminal that works differently though.

Comment: @user4581301 It's Command Prompt (cmd.exe)

Comment: If you execute it in command prompt, is it has the same behavior as CLion?

Comment: for me code blocks too used to wait like that.

Comment: I <expletive deleted>ing hate how Visual Studio does code completion. If CLion is worse I can't imagine how bad it must be.

Comment: I've launched .exe file from the directory, and proper behavior was observed. Indeed, CLion affects the code in its own manere. So, I guess, I just should embrace that fact, or maybe there is some detour of this?